# Spring Data JPA querying with transitive sorting

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I got a problem with simple Spring Data issue. Let's assume we got two entities.

```
public class Request {

    // all normal stuff

    @ManyToOne
    private Document doc;

}


public class Document {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

}
```

Simple relation. My question is - is it possible to retrieve `Request` entities using `Spring Data Method-DSL` and sorting by `Document`? So what I want to achieve is to create repository method like:

```
public List<Request> findAllOrderByDoc()
```

or similar:

```
public List<Request> findAllOrderByDocId()
```

Unfortunately when I try that I am given error message saying that there is no `Doc` field or it cannot be mapped to long. I assume it is possible to be done using `QueryDSL` and predicates but I am wondering if this pretty obvious and simple thing can be done by plain Spring Data?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but dosent Spring Data work by Class name?  What happens when you change Doc to Document?

Comment: @ConMan no, spring-data uses the field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure.

you need to provide the direction:

```
public List<Request> findAllOrderByDocAsc()
public List<Request> findAllOrderByDocDesc()
```